# Initializing two-dimensional array in a function with malloc()

Tags: c, arrays, function, malloc, 2d

I've got a problem.
I need to write a function which will allocate any 2D array with malloc() but I'm lost and have no idea what might be wrong.
Here is what I wrote so far:

```
void matrix_ini(int **arr, int SIZE_X, int SIZE_Y);

int main() {

        int **arr;
        matrix_ini(arr, 2, 3);

        return 0;
}

void matrix_ini(int **arr, int SIZE_X, int SIZE_Y) {

        srand(time(NULL));

        arr = malloc(SIZE_X * sizeof *arr);

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_X; i++) {

                arr[i] = malloc(SIZE_Y * sizeof arr);
        }   

        //initializing array with some numbers:

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_X; i++) {

                for (int j = 0; j < SIZE_Y; j++) {

                        arr[i][j] = rand()%10;

                }   
        }   
}
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?
Please be gentle, I just started learning. Any tips are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problem #1:

This:

```
arr = malloc(SIZE_X * sizeof(*arr));
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
arr = malloc(SIZE_X * sizeof(int*));
```

Which is OK for your purpose.

But this:

```
arr[i] = malloc(SIZE_Y * sizeof(arr));
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
arr[i] = malloc(SIZE_Y * sizeof(int**));
```

Which is **not** OK for your purpose.

So change it to this:

```
arr[i] = malloc(SIZE_Y * sizeof(int));
```

### Problem #2:

If you want a function to change the value of a variable that you call it with, then you have to call it with **the address** of that variable. Otherwise, it can change the value of that variable **only locally** (i.e., within the scope of the function). This pretty much forces you to change the entire prototype, implementation and usage of function `matrix_init`:

```
void matrix_init(int*** arr, int SIZE_X, int SIZE_Y)
{
    int** temp_arr;

    temp_arr = malloc(SIZE_X * sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_X; i++)
    {
        temp_arr[i] = malloc(SIZE_Y * sizeof(int));
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE_Y; j++)
        {
            temp_arr[i][j] = rand()%10;
        }
    }

    *arr = temp_arr;
}
```

Then, in function `main`, you should call `matrix_init(&arr,2,3)`.

### Problem #3:

You should make sure that you release any piece of memory which is dynamically allocated during runtime, at some later point in the execution of your program. For example:

```
void matrix_free(int** arr, int SIZE_X)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_X; i++)
    {
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);
}
```

Then, in function `main`, you should call `matrix_free(arr,2)`.